# What could cause a static resource to be unavailable on Lightning Community (Experience)?

Tags: lightning-community, cors, experience-cloud

I have a Lightning Community (Experience) where we are using CMS Connect to pull in a header and footer from a static resource. [image: CMS Connect Config]

The resources there are not loading, though. In the Builder tool, they come back with

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://removed.cs110.force.com/s/sfsites/c/resource/Support_Community2/SiteHeader.html' from origin 'https://removed.livepreview.salesforce-communities.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

When I view the published site, the browser console has:

```
503 (Service Unavailable)
```

On that resource.

The resource has the Cache Control set to public. I've tried adding the livepreview domain to the general CORS list in setup. I found an article about a release update (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000355604&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1) that can break static resource, but that update is not active.

Any ideas? It feels like it will be something silly.

Comment: try disabling locker service for the community, Go to Experience Builder > Setting > Security & Policy > Set CSP security level to relaxed and disable locker service

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it didn't make any difference. It was worth a try to see if it would give me any extra information but, obviously, disabling Locker Service is not generally a long-term solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a configuration problem around CMS Connect. When you create a sandbox, the URLs keep their production values.

If you're using a custom domain in production, then you need to be careful to change both the server location and also the Root Path and CSS URL path i.e.

When the sandbox is created, it looks like this:

[image: custom domain settings]

And you need all three changes highlighted to refer to the sandbox community properly:

[image: sandbox domain settings]